# Button Counter on Arduino does not transfer data to Processing

Tags: arduino, serial-port, int, processing, arduino-ide

I am looking to integrate Arduino controls and Processing Interface. In my Arduino code, there are three buttons attached to pin a1, a0 and d0 (all digitalRead).

```java
int x;// assigned to A0 input
int y;// assigned to A1 input
int z; //assigned to D0 input
int votes[3]={0,0,0};

void setup() {
  // initialize the serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // wait while littleBits Arduino module is not connected to Serial Port
  // this should not take long at all
  while(!Serial);
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // first we need to read the values from the BUTTONS

  x = digitalRead(A0);
  // read and assign the value of analog input A0 to the variable Hillary
  y = digitalRead(A1);
  // read and assign the value of analog input A0 to the variable Trump
  z = digitalRead(0);
  // read and assign the value of digital input 0 to the variable @FaradayScienceCat

  // next we need to send these values to Processing
  // Processing is expecting a particular format that looks like this "123,456 "
  // The format is: number | ',' | number | ' '
  // The ',' is used to tell the end of the first sensor value
  // The ' ' is used to determine the end of the second value and the packet as a whole

  if(digitalRead(A0) == HIGH) 
    {
    votes[0]=votes[0]+1;
    }
   else if(digitalRead(A1) == HIGH)
    {
    votes[1]=votes[1]+1;
    }
   else if(digitalRead(0) == HIGH) 
    {
    votes[2]=votes[2]+1;
     }

  // next we need to send these values to Processing
  // Processing is expecting a particular format that looks like this "123,456 "
  Serial.println(votes[0]);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(votes[1]);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(votes[2]);

  // After we send the values we need to wait a moment for the Serial port
  delay(200);
}
```

When button is pressed it is being sent to Processing to display as a bar graph, going up with every push. So if button 1 is pressed, the first bar graph will increase by a bit, etc.

```java
import processing.serial.*;

// Serial Port variables
Serial myPort;
String buff = "";
String buff1 = "";
String buff2 = "";
String buff3 = "";
int index = 0;
int NEWLINE = 10;

// Store the last 256 values from the sensors so we can draw them.
int[] valuesx = new int[256];
int[] valuesy = new int[256];
int[] valuesz = new int[256];

// setup() is where the Processing sketch is intitialized. This happens first thing
// sketch is run and only executes once.

void setup()
{ 
  // set size of the window 
  size(512, 512);
  // turn on anti-aliasing, this makes things look smoother 
  smooth();
  println(Serial.list()); // use this to determine which serial port is your Arduino
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

// draw() happens every frame of the sketch. This is where all the calculations are made.
// When draw() is finished executing, it executes again, over and over.
void draw() {
  // set the background to littleBits purple
  background(87, 36, 124);
  // set stroke weight(thickness of the line) to 5 pixels
  strokeWeight(5);

  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {

    stroke(247, i);
    // draw the line (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    line(85, valuesx[i]+200, 85, valuesx[i + 1]+200);
    line(245, valuesy[i]+200, 245, valuesy[i + 1]+200);
    line(425, valuesz[i]+200, 425, valuesz[i + 1]+200);
  }

   // Check the Serial port for incoming data
  while (myPort.available () > 0) {
    // if there is data waiting...
    // execute serialEvent() function. Look below to see how SerialEvent works.
    serialEvent(myPort.read());
  }
}  

// serialEvent controls how incoming serial data from the littleBits Arduino module is handled
void serialEvent(int serial)
{
  if (serial != NEWLINE) {
    // Store all the characters on the line.
    buff += char(serial);
  } 
  else {
    // The end of each line is marked by two characters, a carriage
    // return and a newline.  We're here because we've gotten a newline,
    // but we still need to strip off the carriage return.
    buff = buff.substring(0, buff.length()-1);
    index = buff.indexOf(",");
    buff1 = buff.substring(0, index);
    buff2 = buff.substring(index+1, buff.length());
    buff3 = buff.substring(index+2, buff.length());

    // Parse the String into an integer.  We divide by 4 because
    // analog inputs go from 0 to 1023 while colors in Processing
    // only go from 0 to 255.
    int x = Integer.parseInt(buff1)/2;
    int y = Integer.parseInt(buff2)/2;
    int z = Integer.parseInt(buff3)/2;

    // Clear the value of "buff"
    buff = "";

    // Shift over the existing values to make room for the new one.
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
      valuesx[i] = valuesx[i + 1];
      valuesy[i] = valuesy[i + 1];
      valuesz[i] = valuesz[i + 1];
    }

    // Add the received value to the array.
    valuesx[255] = x;
    valuesy[255] = y;
    valuesz[255] = z;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I press the button, nothing is displayed in the ProCessing.

Answer (score 0):

You only read from the serial port once, in the `setup()` function.

Looking at your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491993/integrating-arduino-and-processing-button-counter), it looks like you forgot your `serialEvent()` function.

Comment: I added a comma to the Arduino code, so now it's listening for one, but still no change in the bar graph... I feel like the issue is in here?          line(85, valuesx[i]+200, 85, valuesx[i + 1]+200);
    line(245, valuesy[i]+200, 245, valuesy[i + 1]+200);
    line(425, valuesz[i]+200, 425, valuesz[i + 1]+200);

Comment: @K.Nadkina Why do you think that's where your problem is? Your code never receives a serial event. You never set the values in your arrays. That's what's causing your error. When you press a button, what code in your Processing sketch do you expect to run?

Comment: okay, I updated the serial event in processing below. See the code above. Problem still exists. Can you see what the potential issue could be right now?

Comment: @K.Nadkina In your last question, I asked you to print out the value of `buff`. Have you done that? What is the value?

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand why I need to print out the value of buff. Could you, please, explain or provide a code sample?

Comment: @K.Nadkina The main goal is to understand what your code is doing. To understand what your code is doing, we need to know the actual value of the variables. All of your logic seems to be based off the `buff` variable, so it's the first thing you should check. What do you expect it to contain? What does it contain instead? That's how you figure out problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you forgot to set the pinmode for the buttons you use. you'll want to use `INPUT_PULLUP` or `INPUT` but I couldn't tell you without more information about your button setup.

```
pinMode(0, INPUT);
pinMode(A0, INPUT);
pinMode(A1, INPUT);
pinMode(0, INPUT);
pinMode(0, INPUT);
```